# Can we combine base line Naive Bayes, Multinomial Naive Bayes and Semi-supervised NB?

Tags: nlp, data-science, text-classification, naivebayes, bernoulli-probability

I am working on sentiment analysis on twitter data. I have tried with couple of Naive Bayes models like Baseline Naive Bayes, Multinomial NB, Bernoulli NB, Semi-supervised NB. My question here is to understand if there is a way we can combine the models in below two way to improve perforrmance?

1. NB+MNB+SSNB
2. NB+BNB+SSNB

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Naive way:**
1) Take the average the scores and do final prediction.
2) Do predictions and then take maximum vote

**Machine Learned way:**
You need to use ensemble approach - Do stacking. Prepare a meta-model over these models.

You can refer this https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-ensembles-with-r/ . Things are done here using caret package in R.

Similar things you can do it in python also using flagship library sklearn .